# Problem with React app sending email with SMTP from a contact form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, nodemailer

I am still learning React. Have been doing React for about 2-3 month now and I though I wanted to dip my toe into node and create a contact form that sends me an email whenever someone fills out the form and sends it.

So, I created a component called contactForm.jsx. This is a simple form I am gonna work more on, but I wanted to get the connection with the server working before I did more.
When I deployed the site to my server, everything is in the root folder. In the root folder is also a folder caleld /backend.
This is where I have my server.js file and my .env file for storing the SMTP credentials.

This is my contactForm.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Field, ErrorMessage, Form } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import axios from 'axios';
import './../styles/contact.css';

const ContactForm = () => {
  // Define validation schema using Yup
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string().required('Name is required'),
    email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email').required('Email is required'),
    message: Yup.string().required('Message is required'),
  });

  // Handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    try {
      await axios.post('/send-email', values);
      alert('Email sent successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert('An error occurred while sending the email');
    } finally {
      setSubmitting(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ name: '', email: '', message: '' }}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting }) => (
        <Form className="contact-form">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
            <Field type="text" id="name" name="name" />
            <ErrorMessage name="name" component="div" className="error-message" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
            <Field type="email" id="email" name="email" />
            <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" className="error-message" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="message">Message:</label>
            <Field as="textarea" id="message" name="message" />
            <ErrorMessage name="message" component="div" className="error-message" />
          </div>

          <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

As you can see, this is a very simple form.
From this form, when I submit it, I do get the console.log('Email sent successfully'), so the handleSubmit function works. And in the Network tab I can see that it is using the correct endpoint.

```
POST
    
scheme
    https
host
    URL.com
filename
    /send-email
```

Now, this is my server.js file that is located in the folder /backend

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: './backend/.env' });
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

console.log('Server is running');

// Create a transporter using your SMTP settings
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
  port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.SMTP_USERNAME,
    pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
  },
  logger: true, // Enable logging
  debug: true, // Enable debug output
});

async function sendEmail(name, email, message) {
  try {
    // Send the email
    const info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: process.env.SMTP_SENDER_EMAIL,
      to: process.env.SMTP_RECIPIENT_EMAIL,
      subject: 'New contact from submission',
      text: `
        Name: ${name}
        Email: ${email}
        Message: ${message}
      `,
    });

    console.log('Email sent successfully');
    console.log('Debug:', info.messageId, transporter.getLastMessage());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/send-email', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Sending Email');
  // Retrieve the form data from the request body
  const { name, email, message } = req.body;

  // Call the sendEmail function with the form data
  sendEmail(name, email, message)
    .then(() => {
      // Send a response back to the client-side (React) app
      res.json({ message: 'Email sent successfully' });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error sending email:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred while sending the email' });
    });
});

// Serve React app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'index.html'));
});

const server = app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3001');
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Promise Rejection:', reason);
});

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Server terminated');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

From what I can tell, when I submit the form, I do not see any of the console.log's from this file at all.
I have no errors on the server, in the console or anything.

The problem is that it is not sending the emails.

I have tested the SMTP credentials, those are working. Tested it with a few sites and my own site that has a working contact form in Wordpress.

I have been at this problem for 2-3 days now. I have checked google, asked ChatGPT, asked Blackbox AI and on another forum where a few guys did not see any problems.

I have been working with Node for only 12 days, so I am just at the beginning. But it is hard to find an error when I do not get any errors in the logs or anything.
For me, it looks like contactForm.jsx can't reach server.js but I do not know why anything is happening.

I have started the server by going into SSH and done "node server.js" and checked that it is running with "ps aux"

I have tried to put the SMTP credentials directly into the server.js file to check that since when I removed the credentials from the .env file completely it still did not give any errors. I though maybe server.js could not read the .env file.

But putting the credentials directly into server.js did nothing different.

I have added a lot of console.log's to check if I can see anything.
Only console.log I can see is the first one that says "server is running" and the one on line 70 that is:

```
const server = app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3001');
});
```

I do not know everything I have tried since I have changed these files so many times from suggestions from some people and ChatGPT.

I feel like sending an Email from a contact form can't be that hard, but for a beginner, I noticed that it actually is.

Any bright minds here that can give me a little clue to where my error might be?
Thanks, and have a lovely evening.